# maven repository server

Tags: repository, maven

a simple question about maven repository server

can a pom file have dependencies of jar files 
located on different repositories on the same server ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I understand the question. You can list as many repositories as you like in the POM file. Doesn't matter if the URLs are all on the same server.